# Unable to click on buttons in the page when running scripts via automation selenium with Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am running my scripts in selenium with java, and when the script hit a specific screen, it just froze and does not perform any click action. It identifies the element and clicks on the button , but the application is not updating with the click.

To ensure it is not application issue, I tired manual execution by opening the application in chrome clicking on these buttons. When the scripts are running in chrome and when it reaches that screen and fails,  tired clicking on these buttons manually and it is all frozen there. Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.